# The method getPythonServer() is undefined for the type GatewayServer

Tags: py4j

getting error The method getPythonServer() is undefined for the type GatewayServer in my code:

import py4j.GatewayServer;

public class PythonIntegration {

```
private static GatewayServer gatewayServer;

public String callPythonCode(String question) {
    // Call the Python method using the Py4J gateway
    return (String) gatewayServer.getPythonServer().getPythonClient().execute("predict_intent", question);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create the Py4J gateway server
    gatewayServer = new GatewayServer(new PythonIntegration());
    gatewayServer.start();

    // Start your Java application logic here

    // Stop the Py4J gateway server when done
    gatewayServer.shutdown();
}
```

}

tried everything but nothing seems to be working